# Sending multiple emails with python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to create a daemon which regularly sends me emails and I'm using the following snippet of code to do so.

```
import smtplib
from datetime import date
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email():
    SMTP_PORT = 587
    SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.mail.com'
    SMTP_USERNAME = 'EMAIL'
    SMTP_PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'

    EMAIL_TO = ['email@hotmail.com']
    EMAIL_FROM = 'EMAIL'
    EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Test!'

    DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
    EMAIL_SPACE = ', '
    DATA='Email Content'

    msg = MIMEText(DATA)
    msg['Subject'] = EMAIL_SUBJECT + ' %s' % (date.today().strftime(DATE_FORMAT))
    msg['To'] = EMAIL_SPACE.join(EMAIL_TO)
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_FROM
    mail = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD)
    mail.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_TO, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()
```

However, after 5 emails, even though I've added the senders email to my contact list on outlook/hotmail, the daemon returns the following exception:

Sending email! 1/1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "daemon.py", line 91, in <module>
    send_email()
  File "daemon.py", line 78, in send_email
    mail.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_TO, msg.as_string())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'email@hotmail.com': (550, 'Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable\nFailure sending mail. Try again later')}
```

Can anyone advise on how to get around this? Does anyone know of an email service that has been tested which will allow more than 5 emails or how I configure the smtplib to not stop sending after 5 emails to the same address?

UPDATE: When I change the receiving email address from outlook to gmail (another one of my emails) - it returns the same exception even though I've sent no emails to the gmail SMTP server.

Comment: You can use gmail smtp server. Also check that EMAIL_TO exist.

Comment: Does https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail work for you?